# How to generate unique incrementing and non-repeating integer in a specific range using datetime info in C#

Tags: numbers, generate

I want to generate counter value.

Counter value should be in specific range (for example:  0x1FFF000 - 0x1FFFFFF) and with every execution generated counter value should be greater than previous value with higher bound of max range.

Also, since application should be able to run in anywhere, this counter info should be generated from Date time.

Want to develop this in C#.
Request your help

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I am trying with datetime.now.tostring() ,then removing symbols from it.But no success so far